# Como descargar un archivo subido mediante un formulario usando FileField

Tags: python, django, django-forms

en mi modelo hago uso de un campo de tipo `FileField` para subir un archivo mediante un formulario.

El modelo es el siguiente:

```
from django.db import models
from apps.agenda.models import TimeStampModel

class Evidencia(TimeStampModel):
  Temas= models.TextField(max_length=140,blank = True, null = True)
  Resultados=models.TextField(max_length=140,blank = True, null = True)
  Recomendaciones = models.TextField(max_length=140,blank = True, null = True)
  Archivo = models.FileField(upload_to='evidencias')

  def __unicode__(self):
      return self.Temas
```

Y este es mi `forms.py`:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Evidencia

class EvidenciaForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
        model = Evidencia
        exclude = ('created','modified')
        widgets={
            'Temas':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control','rows':'4','placeholder':'Breve descripcion del evento'}),
            'Resultados':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control','rows':'4','placeholder':'Breve descripcion de los resultados esperados'}),
            'Recomendaciones':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control','rows':'4','placeholder':'Recomendaciones para la siguiente sesion'}),
            'Archivo':forms.FileInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
    }
```

Y en el navegador asi:

[image: Formulario]

Me gustaría me ayuden a saber de qué manera puedo descargar ese archivo mediante un enlace, como lo muestra la imagen siguiente:

[image: Link]

Comment: Como lo ha subido? Donde y como se almacena el archivo subido?

Comment: @EvelynValeria, ¿Puedes editar tu pregunta y poner el código para ver cómo tienes planteado el modelo y/o el formulario para que podamos orientarte? Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes tener un campo en tu modelo para guardar el archivo

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='subcarpeta/')
```

En el settings.py debes establecer estas variables:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '<your_path>/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Modificar el urls.py para que funcione en el entorno de desarrollo:

```
...
if settings.DEBUG is True:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Cuando se guarde el archivo a través de tu ModelForm, en tu template solamente debes mostrar el campo (el cual contiene la url) en un link:

```
<a href="{{ my_model.file.url }}>download</a>
```

Puedes chequearte la [documentación oficial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/files/) o esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418072/accessing-media-files-in-django/6418281#6418281).